# Why are the shops open in Geneva today (on a Sunday)?

Tags: switzerland, shopping

Many places in Europe are notorious for not being open on Sundays. This is especially true in Switzerland. Today, August 30th 2020, for some odd reason, some stores are open.

[Coop](https://www.coop.ch/en/locations/coop-supermarche-geneve-augustins/1960_POS):

> [image: coop]

[Migros](http://migros.ch)

> [image]

The only explanations, given here, are:

> ouverture dimanche

and

> Ouverture exceptionnelle

Which equate to something like Sunday opening and exceptional opening, respectively.

Why are the shops open today?

Comment: Where in Switzerland is this?

Comment: Are you on a desktop PC? What does happen when you hover the mouse over the *i* next to the times for Sunday?

Comment: @KristvanBesien Geneva.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler It just says the same thing: "Ouverture exceptionnelle."

Comment: Note that laws on this in Switzerland are highly decentralised.

Comment: A lovely mix of French and German there - obviously Switzerland. The first link was broken (though is anyway now out of date and the next Sunday and few "additional information" items are clearer).  I believe I've fixed the link.

Answer (score 74):

In Geneva, following a 2018 vote, shops are allowed to open on three Sundays during the year. France has had similar but more permissive regulations for years (with some nuances between regions and large supermarkets constantly pushing the limits) and concerns about losing business to the competition just across the border in Haute-Savoie or Ain is an additional reason for Geneva in particular to allow this. In neighbouring Vaud, the details are left to the municipalities but shops do close on Sunday for the most part ([including this mall](https://centre-manor-chavannes.ch/#horaires-des-magasins), which is actually very close to Geneva).

Apparently, this particular Sunday was chosen as [it is the end of the first school week](https://www.20min.ch/fr/story/magasins-ouverts-les-dimanches-30-aout-13-et-20-decembre-619890484636). Unsurprisingly, the other two Sundays are in the weeks leading to Christmas.

Comment: Same for Germany. Local authorities can allow local shops to open on several Sundays. There is a [website listing these locations](https://www.verkaufsoffener-sonntag.com/) for the next weeks.

Comment: In Germany, those are called "verkaufsoffener Sonntag".

Comment: And *koopzondag* in the Netherlands. But really, French regulations are more relevant here, not mainly as a source of inspiration, but because Geneva is basically a transborder city, with tens of thousands of people crossing the border daily in both directions and some associated governance problems.

Comment: Do you have any links to learn more about being closed on Sundays? As an American, it's a weird concept for the government to decide which days a business is closed.

Comment: @SnakeDoc "As an American" :-D  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_laws_in_the_United_States

Comment: @Sneftel Mind blown. Never once have run into any of these in any of the states I've traveled to. But then again, I guess I'm just lucky I never tried to buy a car on a Sunday in Texas or whatever. Very curious how these have been upheld as constitutional, since all of the examples in your link appear to be grounded in religion (yes I know it says these have been upheld in court, just very strange).

Comment: @SnakeDoc Don't have a link at hand, history differs a bit depending on the country, sometimes religion played a big role, sometimes workers' right was the main concern, sometimes a bit of both. It's just one aspect of labour law among many, along with minimum wage, leave and working time regulations, protection against unfair dismissal, etc. The notion is that employees are not negotiating as equal with employers so the state intervenes to prevent them from being forced to “consent” to something that's not in their interest.

Comment: @SnakeDoc Note that in France, unless there is some local regulation regulating a specific industry (and they do exist), small independent shops may actually open, what's forbidden is having employees work on Sunday. But the owner is free to open the shop. And local rules often mandate closing at least one day during the week, not specifically Sunday. So it can be, e.g., Monday or Tuesday (bakeries or restaurant will often chose another day than Sunday as their “rest” day).

Comment: @Relaxed That part doesn't make sense. In the US, you cannot compel an employee to work 7 days a week (no more than 5 actually), but a store can be open 7 days a week if the owner has enough employees so that none work more than 5 days in a 7 day period. Seems weird to compel the store to close, as-if business owners aren't smart enough to figure out employee scheduling coverage.

Comment: @SnakeDoc Having a shared free day might be more family-friendly so if a employee is forced to work on Sundays it might be detrimental even if he or she does not work more than 5 days in a row.

Comment: @SnakeDoc The rules became very complex over time and are full of compromises and exceptions (e.g. they do not apply to shops in “international tourism areas“ in the center of Paris and some coastal resorts but also to the healthcare sector, some factories, museums and concert venues, etc.) Historically, when that restriction was introduced in France, it was perfectly legal to work 7 days a week. Chosing Sunday had the advantage of being easily enforceable, ensuring the whole family was free on the same day and placating the Catholic church shortly after the 1905 law.

Comment: The more important point is that the key assumption behind all this is that employers cannot be trusted and employees are not in a position to say no. In other words, business owners are certainly assumed to be smart… when it comes to circumventing generic rules. From that perspective, it isn't weird at all for the government to get involved in how businesses are run, even if the details can be (and actually are) endlessly debated.

Answer (score 2):

The exception to the rule are the main stations of SBB/CFF/FFS in larger cities which often include shops for basic needs like food (e.g., Migros) and a pharmacy which are open all days, including Sundays.  Depending on the space available, you may find additional shops there, too.  Since you mention Geneva, see the listing for [Cornavin](https://www.sbb.ch/en/station-services/at-the-station/railway-stations/geneva-station.html) in the city, and [Geneva airport](https://www.sbb.ch/en/station-services/at-the-station/railway-stations/geneve-aeroport-station.html).

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question as those exceptions allow opening on Sundays throughout the year, whereas in OP's question, the shop is apparently open on this specific Sunday, August 30.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be related to the start of the school year: https://www.20min.ch/fr/story/magasins-ouverts-les-dimanches-30-aout-13-et-20-decembre-619890484636

Or long story short: The "shopping associations" applied the canton for particular stores to be legally open on three more Sundays of the year, so that people can shop pencils and stuff for school, and later in the year - holiday stuff.